# In Jest, mock the constructor of a class instantiated in the tested function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to test `getSessionStorage()`.
Inside `getSessionStorage()` I'm calling `new RedisStore(process.env.REDIS_URL)`.
This throws an error because process.env.REDIS_URL is not accessible outside a vpn.

**How can I mock RedisStore.constructor to avoid calling `this.client.connect();` and thus avoid the error?**

RedisStore.js

```
import { createClient } from "redis";

class RedisStore {
  /**
   * @param {string} url
   */
  constructor(url) {
    this.client = createClient({ url });
    this.client.on("error", (err) => console.log("Redis Client Error", err));
    this.client.connect();
  }
  
  async storeCallback(session) {}
  async loadCallback(id) {}
  async deleteCallback(id) {}

}
export default RedisStore;
```

getSessionStorage.js

```
import RedisStore from "./RedisStore";

const getSessionStorage = ()=> {
  return new RedisStore(process.env.REDIS_URL);
}

export default getSessionStorage;
```

getSessionStorage.test.js

```
import getSessionStorage from "./getSessionStorage.js";

describe("getSessionStorage", () => {
  it("should pass", () => {
    expect(getSessionStorage()).toMatchObject({
      storeCallback: expect.any(Function),
      loadCallback: expect.any(Function),
      deleteCallback: expect.any(Function)
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock redis:

```
jest.mock('redis', () => ({
    createClient : jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ 
        on: jest.fn(),
        connect: jest.fn() 
    }),
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @tcconstantin answer, it got close, but RedisStore was still failing for the lack of get and set methods. This is an updated mock with both missing methods in place:

```
jest.mock('redis', () => ({
  createClient: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    on: jest.fn(),
    connect: jest.fn(),
    get: (key: string, cb: any) => cb(),
    set: (args: string[], cb: any) => cb(),
  }),
}));
```

Also, I'd recommend creating this entry in your jest.config.ts

```
"setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./jest.setup.redis-mock.ts"],
```

And a file to configure the mock of your redis called `jest.setup.redis-mock.ts` with the content from the answer, so you don't need to mock redis on every test file.

**IMPORTANT: Notice that I'm using Typescript, for pure javascript please remove the typings and change file extension to ".js".**